# A partition of tenth powers into ten parts with equal sums

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

Is there a natural number n for which the numbers $1^{10},2^{10},3^{10}\ldots, n^{10}$ we can put into 10 groups, such that the sum of the numbers in each group is the same?

Comment: The problem comes from the KöMaL magazine: http://www.komal.hu/verseny/feladat.cgi?a=feladat&f=B4589&l=en It seems we have a cheater who asks illegal help for solving the contest problems of KöMaL.

Comment: @G.Kós: It seems to that you noticed this too late, as the deadline to many of these questions has expired. It is probably best that you inform the contest organizers about what happened, and they can then (hopefully) identify the cheater. Unfortunately it looks like this horse bolted already. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

$$\large n=10^{11}-1=99~999~999~999.$$

I'll show only hint/scheme on small examples.

**A.** Using base $3$, it is easy to show that one can put numbers $\color{gray}{0^2,}$ $1^2, 2^2, ..., (3^3-1)^2$ into $3$ such groups:

\begin{array}{ll|l|l}
&group~ 1. & group~ 2. & group~ 3. \\
\hline
&(000_3)^2 = 0^2 & (001_3)^2 = 1^2 & (002_3)^2 = 2^2 \\
&(011_3)^2 = 4^2 & (012_3)^2 = 5^2 & (010_3)^2 = 3^2 \\
&(022_3)^2 = 8^2 & (020_3)^2 = 6^2 & (021_3)^2 = 7^2 \\
\\
&(101_3)^2 = 10^2 & (102_3)^2 = 11^2 & (100_3)^2 = 9^2 \\
&(112_3)^2 = 14^2 & (110_3)^2 = 12^2 & (111_3)^2 = 13^2 \\
&(120_3)^2 = 15^2 & (121_3)^2 = 16^2 & (122_3)^2 = 17^2 \\
\\
&(202_3)^2 = 20^2 & (200_3)^2 = 18^2 & (201_3)^2 = 19^2 \\
&(210_3)^2 = 21^2 & (211_3)^2 = 22^2 & (212_3)^2 = 23^2 \\
&(221_3)^2 = 25^2 & (222_3)^2 = 26^2 & (220_3)^2 = 24^2 \\
\hline
\sum(\bullet) : & 117 & 117 & 117 \\
\sum(\bullet)^2 : & 2067 & 2067 & 2067 \\
\end{array}

**B.** Using base $3$, same way one can put numbers $\color{gray}{0^3,}$ $1^3, 2^3, ..., (3^4-1)^3$ into $3$ such groups;
and one can put numbers $\color{gray}{0^4,}$ $1^4, 2^4, ..., (3^5-1)^4$ into $3$ such groups;
...

and one can put numbers $\color{gray}{0^{10},}$ $1^{10}, 2^{10}, ..., (3^{11}-1)^{10}$ into $3$ such groups.

**C.** Using base $10$, one can put numbers $\color{gray}{0^2,}$ $1^2, 2^2, ..., (10^3-1)^2$ into $10$ such groups;
and one can put numbers $\color{gray}{0^3,}$ $1^3, 2^3, ..., (10^4-1)^3$ into $10$ such groups;
and one can put numbers $\color{gray}{0^4,}$ $1^4, 2^4, ..., (10^5-1)^4$ into $10$ such groups;
...
and one can put numbers $\color{gray}{0^{10},}$ $1^{10}, 2^{10}, ..., (10^{11}-1)^{10}$ into $10$ such groups.

---

I cannot answer if this number $n=10^{11}-1$ is the smallest possible. I hope it is the smallest possible.

---

---

**Examples** (base $2$):

Using base $2$, one can construct interesting power sums identities:

\begin{array}{rclr}
0+3  
& = &
1+2 
& =3;
\end{array}

\begin{array}{rclr}
0+3+5+6   
& = &
1+2+4+7
& = 14; \\
0^2+3^2+5^2+6^2   
& = &
1^2+2^2+4^2+7^2
& =70; 
\end{array}

\begin{array}{rclr}
0+3+5+6+9+10+12+15   
& = &
1+2+4+7+8+11+13+14
& =60; \\
\small 0^2+3^2+5^2+6^2+9^2+10^2+12^2+15^2   
& = &
\small 1^2+2^2+4^2+7^2+8^2+11^2+13^2+14^2
& =620; \\
\small 0^3+3^3+5^3+6^3+9^3+10^3+12^3+15^3   
& = &
\small 1^3+2^3+4^3+7^3+8^3+11^3+13^3+14^3
& =7200; 
\end{array}

\begin{array}{cccr}
\small 0+3+5+6+9+10+12+15   
& &
\small 1+2+4+7+8+11+13+14
& \\
\small +17+18+20+23+24+27+29+30
& = &
\small +16+19+21+22+25+26+28+31
& =248; 
\\
\scriptsize 0^2+3^2+5^2+6^2+9^2+10^2+12^2+15^2   
& &
\scriptsize 1^2+2^2+4^2+7^2+8^2+11^2+13^2+14^2
& \\
\scriptsize +17^2+18^2+20^2+23^2+24^2+27^2+29^2+30^2
& = &
\scriptsize +16^2+19^2+21^2+22^2+25^2+26^2+28^2+31^2
& =5208; 
\\
\scriptsize 0^3+3^3+5^3+6^3+9^3+10^3+12^3+15^3   
& &
\scriptsize 1^3+2^3+4^3+7^3+8^3+11^3+13^3+14^3
& \\
\scriptsize +17^3+18^3+20^3+23^3+24^3+27^3+29^3+30^3
& = &
\scriptsize +16^3+19^3+21^3+22^3+25^3+26^3+28^3+31^3
& =123008; 
\\
\scriptsize 0^4+3^4+5^4+6^4+9^4+10^4+12^4+15^4   
& &
\scriptsize 1^4+2^4+4^4+7^4+8^4+11^4+13^4+14^4
& \\
\scriptsize +17^4+18^4+20^4+23^4+24^4+27^4+29^4+30^4
& = &
\scriptsize +16^4+19^4+21^4+22^4+25^4+26^4+28^4+31^4
& =3098760; 
\end{array}

$$...$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\large n=10^{11}-1.$$

**Proof** by math. induction:

**1.** Note that one can put numbers $\color{gray}{0,} 1, 2, ..., 99$  into $10$ groups with equal sums:

\begin{array}{c}
~~~~ \color{gray}{00} + 11 + 22 + ... + 88 + 99 \\
= 01 + 12 + 23 + ... + 89 + 90 \\
= 02 + 13 + 24 + ... + 80 + 91 \\
= ... \\
= 09 + 10 + 21 + ... + 87 + 98.
\end{array}

**2.** Suppose we can put $10p$ numbers $\color{gray}{0,} 1, 2, ..., 10p-1$ into $10$ groups
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 & ... & j_1 & k_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 & ... & j_2 & k_2 \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
a_p & b_p & c_p & ... & j_p & k_p \\
\end{array}
such that

$$
a_1+a_2+...+a_p = b_1+b_2+...+b_p = ~~~ ...~~~ = k_1+k_2+...+k_p ~~ = S_1;
$$

$$
a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_p^2 = b_1^2+b_2^2+...+b_p^2 = ~~~ ...~~~ = k_1^2+k_2^2+...+k_p^2 ~~ = S_2;
$$

$$
a_1^l+a_2^l+...+a_p^l = b_1^l+b_2^l+...+b_p^l = ~~~ ...~~~ = k_1^l+k_2^l+...+k_p^l ~~ = S_l.
$$

**3.**
Denote $M = 10^l$. Build numbers
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
A_1 = 0\cdot M  + a_1 & B_1 = 0\cdot M  + b_1 & ... & K_1 = 0\cdot M  + k_1 \\ 
A_2 = 0\cdot M  + a_2 & B_2 = 0\cdot M  + b_2 & ... & K_2 = 0\cdot M  + k_2 \\ 
... & ... & ... & ...\\ 
A_p = 0\cdot M  + a_p & B_p = 0\cdot M  + b_p & ... & K_p = 0\cdot M  + k_p \\
\\ 
A_{p+1} = 1\cdot M  + b_1 & B_{p+1} = 1\cdot M  + c_1 & ... & K_{p+1} = 1\cdot M  + a_1 \\ 
A_{p+2} = 1\cdot M  + b_2 & B_{p+2} = 1\cdot M  + c_2 & ... & K_{p+2} = 1\cdot M  + a_2 \\ 
... & ... & ... & ...\\ 
A_{p+p} = 1\cdot M  + b_p & B_{p+p} = 1\cdot M  + c_p & ... & K_{p+p} = 1\cdot M  + a_p \\
\\ 
......... & ......... & ... & ......... \\
\\
A_{9p+1} = 9\cdot M  + k_1 & B_{9p+1} = 9\cdot M  + a_1 & ... & K_{9p+1} = 9\cdot M  + j_1 \\ 
A_{9p+2} = 9\cdot M  + k_2 & B_{9p+2} = 9\cdot M  + a_2 & ... & K_{9p+2} = 9\cdot M  + j_2 \\ 
... & ... & ... & ...\\ 
A_{9p+p} = 9\cdot M  + k_p & B_{9p+p} = 9\cdot M  + a_p & ... & K_{9p+p} = 9\cdot M  + j_p \\
\end{array}

**4.** $~$ **Prove** that 
$$
A_1+A_2+...+A_{10p} = B_1+B_2+...+B_{10p} = ~~~ ...~~~ = K_1+K_2+...+K_{10p};
$$

$$
A_1^2+A_2^2+...+A_{10p}^2 = B_1^2+B_2^2+...+B_{10p}^2 = ~~~ ...~~~ = K_1^2+K_2^2+...+K_{10p}^2;
$$

$$
A_1^l+A_2^l+...+A_{10p}^l = B_1^l+B_2^l+...+B_{10p}^l = ~~~ ...~~~ = K_1^l+K_2^l+...+K_{10p}^l;
$$

$$
A_1^{l+1}+A_2^{l+1}+...+A_{10p}^{l+1} = B_1^{l+1}+B_2^{l+1}+...+B_{10p}^{l+1} = ~~~ ...~~~ = K_1^{l+1}+K_2^{l+1}+...+K_{10p}^{l+1}.
$$

Denote $D_q = 0^q+1^q+2^q+...+9^q$ ($D_0=10$, $D_1=45$, ...).

Yes, indeed,
$$
A_1+A_2+...+A_{10p} = B_1+B_2+...+B_{10p} = ~~~ ...~~~ = K_1+K_2+...+K_{10p}
$$
$$
= (0+1+2+...+9)\cdot M + 10 S_1 = D_1 M + D_0 S_1. 
$$

$$
A_1^2+A_2^2+...+A_{10p}^2 = B_1^2+B_2^2+...+B_{10p}^2 = ~~~ ...~~~ = K_1^2+K_2^2+...+K_{10p}^2 
$$
$$
= (0^2+1^2+2^2+...+9^2)\cdot  M^2 + 2 \cdot(0+1+2+...+9)\cdot M \cdot S_1 + 10 S_2
$$
$$
= D_2  M^2 + 2 D_1 M S_1 + D_0 S_2. 
$$

$$
... ... ...
$$

$$
A_1^l+A_2^l+...+A_{10p}^l = B_1^l+B_2^l+...+B_{10p}^l = ~~~ ...~~~ = K_1^l+K_2^l+...+K_{10p}^l
$$
$$
= D_l M^l + \binom{l}{l-1}D_{l-1}M^{l-1}S_1 + ... + \binom{l}{1}D_1M^1S_{l-1}+D_0 S_l
$$
$$
=\sum_{q=0}^l \binom{l}{q}D_q M^q S_{l-q}.
$$

$$
A_1^{l+1}+A_2^{l+1}+...+A_{10p}^{l+1} = B_1^{l+1}+B_2^{l+1}+...+B_{10p}^{l+1} = ~~~ ...~~~ = K_1^{l+1}+K_2^{l+1}+...+K_{10p}^{l+1}
$$
$$
= D_{l+1} M^{l+1} + \binom{l+1}{l}D_{l}M^lS_1 + \binom{l+1}{l-1}D_{l-1}M^{l-1}S_2 + ... + \binom{l+1}{1}D_1M^1S_l
$$
$$
+ (a_1^{l+1}+a_2^{l+1}+...+a_p^{l+1}) + (b_1^{l+1}+b_2^{l+1}+...+b_p^{l+1}) + ... + (k_1^{l+1}+k_2^{l+1}+...+k_p^{l+1})
$$
$$
=\sum_{q=1}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{q}D_q M^q S_{l+1-q} + \sum_{t=0}^{10p-1} t^{l+1}.
$$

**Proved.**

---

I am not sure that this $n$ is the smallest possible, but perhaps it is so.